# Say you have a 5% chance of getting your bike stolen each day you leave it outside. What's the probability of the bike getting stolen within a month?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out the probability of an event with a P(x) probability of occurring on a trial. What's the probability of the event happening after n trials?

And also, how many trials would it take for the probability of the event happening to reach a certain probability?

Sorry for the very basic question, but I'm very rusty on my statistics and I don't know how to phrase it to search for it.

My guess would be to exponentiate like so:
P(x after n trials)= P(x)^(1/n), but i can't prove it, and I'm not sure.

Comment: If you want to read up on the probability distribution that models the answer to your question, it is the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

Comment: I suppose you are assuming days are independent.

Comment: @BruceET Yes, thats the assumption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the probability your bike is NOT stolen within $n$ days is

$$ \operatorname{Pr}(\mbox{Bike Not Stolen by day $n$)} = (0.95)^n $$

That's because there is a 0.95 probability it is not stolen on the first day, a 0.95 probability it is not stolen on the second day, etc. Note that this shrinks pretty quick since it is exponential in $n$.

So the probability it is stolen is $1 - (0.95)^n$.  You can easily apply some algebra to find the day on which you achieve some desired risk of having it stolen.